# QSqlTableModel on multiple tables

Tags: qt, qtsql

I am using Qt's *Model View Programming* on a database, where an object is represented using multiple tables. Assume the following object and coresponding database tables which perfectly fit my design:

```
TagObject
  - id
  - name
  - usable
  - information

tag_table
  - id
  - name
  - usable

tag_info_table
  - id_ref
  - info
```

As you may see, the *information* property is separated into another table to prevent existence of *NULL* because this property is optional.

In the database I have a view which aggregates the values into one *'table'* which can be queried using `QSqlTableModel`. Note that **INSERT**ing data is not possible this way. As far as I could understand, the database design is not supported by Qt's classes, neither `QSqlTableModel` nor `QSqlRelationalTableModel` do support this. (Additionally `QSqlQueryModel` does not support inserts at all so this is out of question.)

Am I missing something? Is there any way to do this using Qt's SQL classes? Or is the only way to achive this subclassing `QSqlQueryModel` as pointed out [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlquerymodel.html#details)?

> The model is read-only by default. To make it read-write, you must subclass it and reimplement setData() and flags(). Another option is to use QSqlTableModel, which provides a read-write model based on a single database table.

---

**Edit:** As for subclassing I found [this reference](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtsql-querymodel-example.html) as a nice entry point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally, the view should have appropriate triggers that will modify the underlying tables. Make the view writable and your problems go away: you can use a `QSqlTableModel` directly on that view, then.

Alternatively, you can have a `QSqlTableModel` for each table, and then write a custom proxy model that supports inserts and translates between the source models and forms the writable view. It'll be more work than writing the SQL triggers.

Comment: Two nice approaches different to mine, nice. I will dig into that.

Comment: I ended up using a trigger function on the view which works perfectly. I like the fact to put as much logic as possible into the database. Thanks!

Comment: Came into another question which is related I think: Using triggered views, how to handle *n:m* relations which are not inside the view? Any good way to get them into one? I have *surrogate key* tables which map ids of two tables to get the relation.

Comment: I thought about filling one column of the view, typed as array, with the primary keys of the foreign table. Application side wise I may unpack the array and reolve to the foreign table without losing database constraint checks. May there be issues?

Comment: Here is a problem when you need to optimize the sql query (indexes, hints, etc.). If you have 3 separate tables, it's easy. If you have one view, it is very difficult. But thank you for answear. It's wery usable for me.